# Birational Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Given a polynomial map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to V\subset \mathbb{R}^3 $ defined as follows:
$$
(z_1,z_2)\mapsto (2z_1-z_2, 2z_1^2-z_2^2, 2z_1^3-z_2^3)
$$
This map defines a Variety ($V$) of dimension $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is this variety bi-rationally equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, it is. And the answer is in your other question.